# Database n:1:m relation

Tags: database

I am a beginner in db design. Is there such a kind of relationship as n:1:m?

For example, each 'person' could be any 'type', such as ['introvert', 'extrovert'], each 'type' of person has many 'personality', such as ['shy', 'brave'] , how can i define this kind of relationship.

Would it be:

```
Person Table:

id : int (pk)
typeId: int (reference Type table)
name : string


Type Table:

id : int (pk)


Personality Table:

id : int (pk)
typeId: int (reference Type table)
personality: string
```

It looks very strange to me, especially the type table seems can replaced by an enum in the Personality table and Person table. I am not sure where i do wrong, and also how should i call this kind of relationship?